# Push a git local repository to github

Tags: git

I am new in git. I am learning git. While I am pushing my repo in github I got errors like below.

`$ git push origin master`

**ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
And the repository exists.**

What can be the solution ??

Thanks

Foysal

Comment: Do you have write access to the repository you're trying to push to? Have you configured your credentials/SSH keys properly? Look at github's help center, they have some useful information there.

Comment: check the .git folder inside your project folder. Look for the file exclude and check how the branches are defined

Comment: I am new in git and github. I am following this `[link] http://nithinbekal.com/2010/installing-git-and-pushing-repo-to-github/` tutorial. I am using my github account `[link] https://github.com/foysal`. Suggest me if you have any effective tutorial.

Comment: Did you put the correct repository using git remote add origin <url>? Are you behind a firewall that blocks port 22, in which case you'd have to use https. A good first step to learning git is: http://try.github.com/